# What is the most efficient way to render a HTML Table in Razor C#

Tags: c#, html, razor, razorengine

I am trying to create a html table that has about 5,000 rows.
I am retrieving the data from a SQL database which is grabbed in less than a second (ive only included the relevant code):

```
ViewBag.Jobs = dbContext.Jobs.Where(a=>a.State == "Completed");
```

This call is quick enough.

However the bottle neck is in the razor code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach (Job job in jobs)
{
    <tr>
       <td>@job.id</td>
       <td>@job.Name</td>
       <td>@job.Description</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

Is there a more efficient way to render the html table? I know I could convert the  to  using classes, but I don't believe it'll make noticeable difference?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is with Razor generating the table, and not the browser attempting to render it?  That's a very large table.

Comment: Maybe have it in a Web API Controller and call the data with $.JSON in JavaScript? This would depend on your environment and how much you're allowed to change. You could also limit the amount of records that are displayed in the table. 5000 records seems a little insane to view.

Comment: You have no need to call .ToList().  Doing so forces a list to be materialized in memory, which you don't use. Just leave it as an `IEnumerable<Job>`.

Comment: @EricJ., the `dbContext.Jobs.Where...` will return an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable`, which will end up being materialized into memory the minute he starts `foreach`ing over it, so it really doesn't matter whether the `ToList` exists or not, ultimately every item in the set will be retrieved from the database and materialized as an object.

Comment: @CraigW. Creating a list is more expensive than consuming the objects one at a time.  Not much more in the context of everything else that is happening, but it is a cost (and it also consumes memory unnecessarily, which is never a good thing in a web app).

Comment: @EricJ. I threw together two tests, one using `IQuerable` and one using `ToList`. With 11,072 rows in the table the `ToList` consistently performed very slightly faster. Both executed in ~3000 ms with the `ToList` version being about ~100 ms faster. It's an optimization that's hardly worth doing but I like dealing in empirical facts. I didn't compare memory but in both cases all the objects need to be created I doubt the difference is significant, although GC *might* reduce the IQueryable footprint slightly if old instances get collected before the loop is finished...

Comment: ... If there was a possibility the loop wouldn't execute or would be terminated early then `IQueryable` becomes slightly more efficient (by ~100 ms when executing half the loop) as not all the objects would be instantiated, but as it stands the `ToList` is actually the more efficient choice (by an insignificant margin).

Comment: @CraigW. I don't see how ToList could possibly be faster as it has to do all of the work done in the IQueryable variant, plus create the list (which should be trivial overhead, but is overhead nonetheless).  Benchmarks are hard to do accurately (IO caching, CPU caching, other tasks running on the machine, and other factors can all skew your results).  It might be interesting to post your benchmark as a question, asking why the ToList version is faster in spite of the extra overhead (if you do, link it here as I would love to see it).

Comment: Maybe ToList permits bulk allocation of memory? ToList hopefully just creates a list of pointers to the original query resultset values.

Answer (score 0):

5000 rows is a lot of rows to show on a browser. 
Any approach that you take will need to iterate through the rows to generate the output, so you might want to consider using some pagination to render the data.

Using html parsers like KnockoutJS or AngularJS to bind your element will help to render the page faster than this one...

Or you could consider using some ajax call and render the data after the page is loaded.

Comment: `Using html parsers like KnockoutJS or AngularJS to bind your element will help to render the page faster than this one...` References/proof?

Comment: yes Ajax was my plan B.. My plan A was to render 5000 rows, hide the rows I need to show. So it makes for instant search

Comment: @EricJ. Using Razor views like this means that the generation of the output html is happening in the server side and then the generated html will be downloaded into the browser and rendered, where as in the html parsing, the html templates(not populated) + json data will be downloaded into the browser and then the html parser will generate the content. so in case of razor view, the size of the html that is being downloaded to the browser is exponentially higher than the case that we only send the json and the html template to the browser.

Comment: @Aram: You have to download the JSON over the wire, too.  I expect there is a linear relationship between the size of the generated HTML and the size of the JSON data, not an exponential one.  The HTML representation is not particularly bloated compared to the JSON representation, so I'm not even sure which is going to be larger.  I also see no evidence of any performance benefit to your approach; in fact, it may be slower.